# create an erb template or use nokogiri to generate xml files?

Tags: xml, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to XML and need to generate several different XML files based on different XSD files. Is it feasible to use ERB for this, I am familiar with it from Rails. What are the pros and cons of using ERB or another library like libxml2 or nokogiri to accomplish this? In the future I would also like to use Ruby to validate XML files from other people against those same XSD I mention above. How would you approach this problem?

I'm hoping to wrap generating, sending, and receiving these XML files in a REST web-service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use .builder files rather than .erb if the [guide section here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action) is correct.

> The actual rendering is done by subclasses of
>   ActionView::TemplateHandlers. This guide does not dig into that
>   process, but it’s important to know that the file extension on your
>   view controls the choice of template handler. Beginning with Rails 2,
>   the standard extensions are .erb for ERB (HTML with embedded Ruby),
>   and **.builder for Builder (XML generator)**.

[emphasis mine]

Comment: How does the XSD factor into generating the xml response? Is it part of the process? Or should I just use it as a guide to make sure my xml is correct?

Comment: @opensourcechris Your Builder file will look similar to the XSD but with variable parameters in places that your controller will supply data for (e.g. `<name>@user_name</name>`).